# Dynamic Array & Array_unintersect_assoc() || Array_unintersect()

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, array-intersect

Having trouble trying to compare to dynamic arrays of objects.

Object:

```
class Skill
{
    public $SkillID;
    public $Profficiency;
    public $Required;
    public $Source;

    public function __construct($SkillID,$Prof,$Req,$Src){
        $this->SkillID = $SkillID;
        $this->Profficiency = $Prof;
        $this->Required = $Req;
        $this->Source = $Src;
    }
}
```

What I am doing is assigning 2 people their sets of skills. Person A & B can have any number of Skills.
Skill::Source identifies that its from person A via a Boolean.

```
$SkillMatches = array_uintersect_assoc($this->Person_A->Skills,$this->Person_B->Skills,array($this, 'SkillIDComparison'));

private function SkillIDComparison($Skill_A,$Skill_B){
    print_r($Skill_A);
    echo '<br>';
    print_r($Skill_B);
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    if ($Skill_A === $Skill_B) {
        return 0;
    } elseif ($Skill_A > $Skill_B) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

My issue is that if say Person_A has 5 Skills, and Person_B has 2 Skills, Array_uintersect_assoc() , does not check all 5 skills of Person_A

```
Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 6 [Profficiency] => 1 [Required] => 0 [Source] => 1 ) 
Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 3 [Profficiency] => 2 [Required] => 0 [Source] => ) 

Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 7 [Profficiency] => 1 [Required] => 0 [Source] => 1 ) 
Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 5 [Profficiency] => 2 [Required] => 1 [Source] => )
```

Now if I use Array_uintersect(), when the callable function is called it does not assign Person_A::Skills to $Skill_A and Person_B::Skills to $Skill_B respectfully, as well it seems to be random at which Skills are assigned to the parameters inside the Callable function.

```
$SkillMatches = array_uintersect($this->Person_A->Skills,$this->Person_B->Skills,array($this, 'SkillIDComparison'));

Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 7 [Profficiency] => 1 [Required] => 0 [Source] => 1 ) 
Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 6 [Profficiency] => 1 [Required] => 0 [Source] => 1 ) 

Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 8 [Profficiency] => 1 [Required] => 0 [Source] => 1 ) 
Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 7 [Profficiency] => 1 [Required] => 0 [Source] => 1 ) 

Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 5 [Profficiency] => 2 [Required] => 1 [Source] => ) 
Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 3 [Profficiency] => 2 [Required] => 0 [Source] => ) 

Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 6 [Profficiency] => 1 [Required] => 0 [Source] => 1 ) 
Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 3 [Profficiency] => 2 [Required] => 0 [Source] => ) 

Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 6 [Profficiency] => 1 [Required] => 0 [Source] => 1 ) 
Skill Object ( [SkillID] => 5 [Profficiency] => 2 [Required] => 1 [Source] => )
```

as you can see here half the time the function is called its not even comparing from the two different people. Only the last two calls actually compare Person_A and Person_B.

Any Assistance would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You receive  two objects in function `SkillIDComparison`. And if you want compare properties SkillID, so take them by `$Skill_A->SkillID`.

So, change all next lines

```
if ($Skill_A === $Skill_B) {
    return 0;
} elseif ($Skill_A > $Skill_B) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return -1;
}
```

by

```
return $Skill_A->SkillID - $Skill_B->SkillID;
```

Use `array_uintersect`because you want compare values but keys.

I don't know whether this construction `array($this, 'SkillIDComparison')` is correct. But if use 3rd argument as 'SkillIDComparison' all works OK

Comment: Take a closer look at my question and the Output i provided. My problem is not the comparison inside SkillIDComparison, its whats being presented to that function take a look at the second Output. Source = 1 means it was from Person A. so that means for the first 2 calls to the function person a is being compared against itself

Comment: as well as the 3rd call how it comapares person b against person b.

Comment: i tried and received a good result. To understand  your output , place `var_export ($this->Person_A->Skills);` and `var_export($this->Person_B->Skills);` before calling intersect

Comment: How does calling var export before intersect explain my issue. Person_A is an array of objects. The issue is when given TWO array of objects why is array_Uintersect Mixing  those two arrays. it should be comparing them and providing weights to each iteration of each array not comparing person_a array to itself.

Comment: @DirtyRedz look there `https://eval.in/372817` there it is clear how the intersect work. It sorts arrays and then find matches